# How to allow users to customize text field with styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textbox

I am currently working on a project for school and am required to create a blog. Part of our assignment is to create an input field that would allow users to customize the styling of their text within the field. Although I have looked around, I have had no luck in finding what it is that I am looking for. For clarification, the goal is to create a field that resembles the field on here when creating a post (Photo included below).

I am assuming that Javascript and/or JQuery is required, although I am unsure where to begin. Features would include text styling, addition of links, keeping track of [return]s (to create new paragraphs) and any other HTML/CSS elements.

Below, I will include examples of what it is exactly that I am wanting in case I am in any way unclear.

Thank you in advance for any help/guidance!

Example 1:
[image: Example 1]

Example 2:
[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* create it yourself!

I threw this together in a couple of minutes. It's pretty rudimentary, but if you want to build it yourself, this could be a starting point for you:

```js
var areas = document.getElementsByClassName('augmented-textarea');

var commands = [{
  display: "<b>B</b>",
  f: function(text) {
    return "**" + text + "**";
  },
}, {
  display: "<i>I</i>",
  f: function(text) {
    return "_" + text + "_";
  },
}, ];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(areas, initTextarea);

function initTextarea(t) {
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('textarea-wrapper');
  var bar = document.createElement('div');
  bar.classList.add('textarea-bar');

  commands.forEach(function(c) {
    var b = document.createElement('button');
    b.type = 'button';
    b.innerHTML = c.display;
    b.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (t.selectionStart === t.selectionEnd)
        return;

      var v = t.value,
        ss = t.selectionStart,
        se = t.selectionEnd,
        prefix = v.slice(0, ss),
        suffix = v.slice(se),
        target = v.substring(ss, se),
        changed = c.f(target);
      t.value = prefix + changed + suffix;
      t.selectionStart = ss;
      t.selectionEnd = ss + changed.length;
      t.focus();
    });
    bar.appendChild(b);
  });

  t.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, t);
  t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
  wrapper.appendChild(bar);
  wrapper.appendChild(t);
}
```

```css
.textarea-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.textarea-bar {
  background-color: #ddd;
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.textarea-bar button {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.augmented-textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="augmented-textarea">Select some text and press one of the buttons above!</textarea>
```

Each command is registered in the `commands` array, with HTML for a button, and an instruction to do with the selected text.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I'll look to expand this more.

Answer (score 2):

Just use tinymce - unless your assignment is to create the actual control itself, which is far more complicated than even creating a blog unfortunately.

Get TinyMCE here: 
https://github.com/tinymce

or at their site:
https://www.tinymce.com/

Then create a textarea element and initiate the control:

Include TinyMCE at the bottom of your page and include this script below that include.

Example here @ the TinyMCE site: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/#liveexample

**HTML:**

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

**Javascript:**

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
  ],
  toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  content_css: [
    '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan, I certainly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor for this. There are lot of text editor plugins are available.

This may help you : http://ckeditor.com/

**Note:** Have a look in to the Licence also before using the editor.

Comment: Thank you very much! This turned out to be easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

A free and open source option is https://quilljs.com/.

From their quickstart guide:

```
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```