# Allow users to style a text

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a mobile app using Flutter and I want to allow users to customize the text putting some parts into **bold** or *italic* and others into normal style.
I need any help for that.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried/researched?

Comment: I have seen this [JavaScript link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953345/how-to-allow-users-to-customize-text-field-with-styling)

Comment: you need to work with a RichText widget and make it load style and widgets dynamically

Comment: Ok! Thanks for all. I'm going to try